# Structure of Finite Commutative Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

Is every finite commutative ring $A$ a direct product of finite algebras over $\mathbb Z/p^n$?

Comment: You assume that $A$ has a unit? My first thought is that every finite commutative ring is Artinian. So by the structure theorem for Artinian rings may be written as a direct product of Local Artinian rings. So it suffices to prove the result for Local finite commutative rings.

Comment: ... and local algebras have only trivial idempotents, so that the characteristic has to be a prime power.

Comment: yes, The ring is assumed to be unital.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825661

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A finite commutative ring is artinian, so it is a finite product of finite artinian local rings. Let $R$ be a finite commutative local ring and $\phi:\mathbb Z\to R$ the canonical ring homomorphism ($n\mapsto n1_R$). Then $\ker \phi=n\mathbb Z$, $n>1$. It follows that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R$. Since the idempotents of $R$ are trivial, the same holds for $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. This implies that $n$ is a power of a prime, and we are done. (More on finite local rings you can find [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98883/finite-local-rings).)

Comment: The classification of artinian rings is a total overkill here.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If you think that the Chinese Remainder Theorem is an overkilling tool, then you are right!

Answer (score 17):

Sure. A ring homomorphism $\prod_i R_i \to S$ corresponds to a decomposition $S =\prod_i S_i$ and a family of ring homomorphisms $R_i \to S_i$ (namely $S_j=S \overline{e_j}$ where $\overline{e_j}$ is the image of the canonical idempotent $e_j \in \prod_i R_i$). Thus, an algebra over a product is a product of algebras.

A finite ring has some characteristic $n \neq 0$, i.e. is an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}/n \cong \prod_p \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(n)}$.

Comment: This is much simpler than what I had in mind. There's also some more of characterizing finite commutative rings [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7133/classification-of-finite-commutative-rings).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: What exactly do you mean by "canonical idempotent"?

Comment: The element $(0,\dotsc,1,\dotsc,0)$.